# Places in and around Bangalore

Tags: india, local-knowledge, bangalore

Like most of them in Bangalore, I am a software professional, new to the city. I heard a lot about Bangalore and that there are so many beautiful locations in and around the city. Please share a few places you know, where I can go and just relax.

Comment: happy2Help, welcome to Travel.SE, this kind of question can't really be answered objectively as different people have different views and like different things. In your question you didn't mention what you enjoy doing or what kind of locations you are looking for. Please revise your question or it will be closed. Enjoy Travel.SE!

Comment: Closed for reasons mentioned by rlesko

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee I suggest making wikis for each city, The wiki should include important information about the city and some major interests in it and some important phone numbers and so on.. just a suggestion.

Comment: Definitely not as there are guidebooks which serve exact same purpose and [Wiki Travel site](http://wikitravel.org) in case you can't get a paper copy. Although I would love more community wikis here, definitely not for questions like these because (as it was mentioned), it is very subjective what a each person would like. If you still want to express you wish for such community wikis, please make a suggestion in [Travel Meta](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Will keep it in mind from next post.. Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bangalore is a city full of identical shopping malls. There isn't much to see in the city itself. There is Lal Bagh, Cubbon Park, Vidhana Soudha, Bangalore Palace, HAL Museum, Visvesvaraya Technological Museum - that's it, I guess. There are tons of beautiful weekend getaways very close to Bangalore - Nandi Hills, Masinagudi, Bandipur, Mysore, Ooty, Yercaud etc.
You could go for treks around Bangalore - try YHAI (Youth Hostels Association of India) or BMC (Bangalore Mountaineering Club) or some other trekking group.

Comment: @happy2Help: You're welcome.

Comment: Hi, I would suggest Nandi hills.. Nandi hills is a must see place near Bangalore. Wonderful Journey. Wonderful pictorial spot. Awesome view.

This place is 70KM from Bangalore Bus. Try to reach before sunrise as this is is the wonderful view from this hills.

Attractions: Totally non commercial place. Just go and enjoy the view. You will be entertained by Natural sites. Parks for children, a old temple, valley view and obviously sunrise.

Best time to visit: All year, though if you’re one of those who enjoy rain : May-July ; fog: Nov-Jan

Nandi Hills Video: https://youtu.be/NNntxL1-5A0